# Infer type of _arr in class based on method usages in typescipt

Tags: typescript

If I have something like

```js
class A{
  _arr: /* dont know what to write here*/ = []
  addEl<T>(el: T): {
    this._arr.push(el)
  }
}
```

and I want to use it like this

```js
const instance = new A();
instance.addEl<"whatever">("whatever");
// type of instance._arr should be ["whatever"]
instance.addEl<number>(42)
// type of instance._arr should be ["whatever", number]
```

is that possible? And what would I have to do for the type of _arr?

Comment: No, this is not possible as written.  This would require the type of `instance` to change after each call to `addEl()`.  You can sometimes sort of do this with [assertion methods](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) but in this case you are not even narrowing, since the length-2 tuple `["whatever", number]` is not assignable to the length-1 tuple `["whatever"]`.  If you're willing to use multiple objects with one type each instead of multiple types for the same object, you can do [this](//tsplay.dev/WKVkpm). Does that meet your needs?

Comment: In either case I can write up an answer unless I'm missing something about your question.  Let me know.

Comment: yea thanks, that is pretty much what I guessed. If you want to you can write an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Just for why I was asking I am currently using this non-optimal solution to implement abstract static methods in an abstract class, see here https://gitlab.rgb-pixl.de/rpck/utils/-/blob/main/src/class/abstractStatic.ts . As far as I know it just is not possible to see meaningful errors at compile time currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As asked, this is impossible.  TypeScript's type system doesn't model arbitrary *mutations* of a value's type.  If a variable is annotated as type `0` then it can't later be changed to a value of type `1`.  The compiler does perform [narrowing via control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) whereby the type of a variable can be seen to get *more specific* based on certain checks or operations, and this does give the compiler some minor ability to track *state changes* of a variable... but it's quite limited.  If you knew for a fact that every call to `instance.addEl()` would only narrow the type of `instance`, then you could try to make `addEl()` an [assertion method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions), but these are brittle and hard to use.  And that's not even available to you, since [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) have a known `length` property, and calling `addEl()` would effectively make `instance._arr.length` change from a value of type `0` to a value of type `1`, something the compiler does not allow:

```
const instance = new A();
instance._arr // should be []
instance._arr.length // should be 0

instance.addEl<"whatever">("whatever");
instance._arr // should be ["whatever"]
instance._arr.length // should be 1, but this is impossible
```

---

Rather than trying to refactor your code to use control flow analysis, my suggestion here would be to embrace TypeScript's strong type system and forget about mutating state.  So instead of having a single instance whose state changes after each call to `addEl()`, you have [immutable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) instances which yield new instances when you call `addEl()`.  It could look like this:

```
const instance0 = A.emptyInstance;
instance0._arr // []
instance0._arr.length // 0

const instance1 = instance0.addEl<"whatever">("whatever");
instance1._arr // ["whatever"]
instance1._arr.length // 1

const instance2 = instance1.addEl<number>(42);
instance2._arr // ["whatever", number]
instance2._arr.length // 2
```

That's not very different from your original example, and now TypeScript can definitely represent this.  Here's how I'd implement it:

```
class A<T extends any[]>{
  static emptyInstance = new A<[]>([]);
  private constructor(public _arr: T) { }
  addEl<U>(el: U): A<[...T, U]> {
    return new A([...this._arr, el]);
  }
}
```

Here the `A` class is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `T`, the type of the `_arr` property.  (Note that I'm using `_arr` as a [parameter property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties), so it exists both as a property of the instance and a parameter to the constructor.)

The type of `addEl()` uses [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) to show that the result will be a new instance of `A` where the tuple type is like `T` with an extra element of type `U` (the type of `el`) appended to it.  While you could just  `push()` the element onto the existing `_arr` property and return `this`, you'd then have to remember never to reuse an instance variable after you call `addEl()`.  By returning a new instance, you're ensuring that the values are immutable to match the immutability of the types.

This version of the code lends itself to [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining), where you don't hold onto intermediate instances unless you need them:

```
const allAtOnce = A.emptyInstance.addEl(true).addEl(0).addEl(new Date);
// const allAtOnce: A<[boolean, number, Date]>
```

---

If this sort of refactoring for immutability works for your use case, great!

If not, then you probably need to give up on having the compiler track the exact current state of the `_arr` property and fall back to an unordered array of unknown elements, and any checking will need to take place only at runtime.

```
// fallback 
class A {
  _arr: any[] = []
  addEl(el: any) {
    this._arr.push(el)
  }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgBAsAUAxg9gOwM4BcwEtkoIYJgUzAF4wF8B3MAQQAoBKAbmk1VwIDoB9bAJx7GDAwSABZwArgBsAJmABGhANoBdZljb4uvHu0n4EAcxQiBQ0RJnzCABmhrWeTdmnSAopIA8AInIjsKfAA3fB4vAD4aHz8A4NDGexxHLT5TYTEpWQUwRSj-IJCvVSgWRI5uPl19IxNBNItMwgBGO2L1JOc3TwRxAFsFHgiAFgAmOgSNZP5a8wyrbNyYgoAaUl7+opKJ8p09Q2NUmcss4egwEGAW6BhJbCQkag8AFTB8AA8AhGl73ABPFTCAN6nYQ4FDoGAvHoABxQPwAkm0CMRSBQHv8aCp4lAwGAoTx0IE8mB4FgeOIYCg4DwaFDxHJJOCwNsAFxgR50MAAsAAX2BHXcHgAqhF8JJWYK6KyqB5FOw5Y8VoLlGFOcCcTx8ChxDwECjKLRZXLjOgkJMVqLlFicbyoDarohUBhEfhrMiqOx8NDYQiHAQmK1fS7JqkVONHNZJpU9jUhLYoPasE7A41kZtw+x+Z4FvlQhFs7EvFi0wRGsHajlfHkCxtnaXtlHqqlmvHYA60MX8MNU7WMy4Bd0+iEhqN-R3hmWhBXojmvCsB+swwRx-Xdo3aicWyTHdhJJIqCgAPKON0er3w529zo0FBk-B0S-uGjWe+ZmhkSgAETyWNqW7QO73Q9HClGU5DgOA9FwOc1hCFYvwCZUWgQbAenwJAoWwJEADEALkTCAGtVWxYkbjuagiJxHEWTAX4VGRUNiJxV9RVZX4OSBRjKONU161pUQaFFMZOJta0Wm5IA)